# CSS: Show div using hover

Tags: html, css

I want to see 2nd div when mouse Over.

HTML

```
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div class="ab">Some content</div>
<div class="abc">Some text here</div>
```

CSS

```
.abc {
    display: none;
}
a:hover + .abc{
    display: block;

}
```

Comment: Try using `~` instead of `+` to make it work with both divs. For example: `a:hover ~ div { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *adjacent sibling combinator* is not exactly what you want. It can only select the div with the class `.ab`, because it's directly following the anchor.

What you want is this:

```
a:hover ~ .abc {
    /*...*/
}
```

This selects every `.abc` which is following a hovered anchor element, but it don't has to be directly before it.

Answer (score 0):

Had some delay reaching SO so this is late. Here a fiddle for my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/F5k4L/

The main issue here uses @kleinfreud's suggestion about an adjacent `div` but weaves in another approach to showing and hiding a `div`:

```
.abc {
    opacity: 0;
}
a:hover ~ .abc{
    opacity: 100;
}
```

This makes sure the space that `div` will take up is reserved to begin with, then showing it when needed.

Comment: Opacity is for visual effects, but to preserve the space even if an element is invisible one should use the `visibility`-property.

Comment: Agreed, `visibility: hidden/visible` ought to be better, but for some reason the `opacity` properties have been more reliable I've found.